# Can the word afforded be used in the following context

Tags: word-usage

> His wealth of experience has **afforded** him the business acumen to
>   quickly identify issues facing the business

Is the word afforded being used correctly here? Is there anything else wrong with that sentence?

I'm writing a short bio about myself for a company profile. Obviously my *wealth of experience* does not extend to the use of the English language.

Comment: Have you looked the word up in any dictionary?  What did you find?  What was it you didn't understand?

Comment: @Centaurus, I think perhaps the OP wrote the sentence and is asking us to proofread it.

Comment: @ link64. Please explain. Who wrote this? What precisely are you asking from us?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK 
Sorry if these questions are not allowed here - if so, I will delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *afforded* is used properly in the provided sentence.

In the future, to determine whether a word can be used within a certain context, I suggest you reference a dictionary and replace the word in question with a definition, applying the proper tense as necessary.

Used as a verb, you are using the following definition of *afforded* found on [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/afforded?s=t):

> to furnish; supply

Substituting in *supply*, we get

> His wealth of experience has **supplied** him the business acumen to quickly identify issues facing the business

This makes sense, so we can conclude that *afforded* works in your sentence.